# undefined method `empty?' for nil:NilClass when trying to add a error validation messege

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to add a validation in my code where if the user puts more than 4 digits it push an error message. I want to be able to add an error message when the user enters in the durations field a number lager than 4 digits the error pops up and reloads the page again.

this was my controller before validation

```
unless params[:searched] 
        @filters[:duration] ||= Hash.new
        @filters[:duration][:durations] = ['1']
        @filters[:duration][:operators] = [:gt]
      end

      if @filters.try(:[],:duration).try(:[],:durations)
        @filters[:duration][:durations].map!(&:to_i)
      end
@recording_metadata = RecordingMetadata.find(@tenant, request.session_options[:id], (start_time..end_time), @filters, additional_options)
```

this is my controller right now where I have my code

```
     unless params[:searched] 
        @filters[:duration] ||= Hash.new
        @filters[:duration][:durations] = ['1']
        @filters[:duration][:operators] = [:gt]
      end

      if @filters.try(:[],:duration).try(:[],:durations)
        @filters[:duration][:durations].map!(&:to_i)
      end
if @filters[:duration][:durations].length <= 4 
        @recording_metadata = RecordingMetadata.find(@tenant, request.session_options[:id], (start_time..end_time), @filters, additional_options)
      else
        Notice.rpush("4 digits")
        save_notice
        render action: :index
      end
```

this is my view where the error is happening at in my view

```
 - unless @recording_metadata.empty?
```

Answer (score 3):

`empty?` doesn't work for `nil`. Try doing `unless @recording_metadata.blank?`. `blank?` is provided by Ruby on Rails.

Comment: I'd probably go with `.nil?` as that seems to be what he's checking, rather than a blank string

Comment: awesome both worked and stopped giving me the error. the only issue i am having now is that even when the user enters a 4 digit number the error still pushes and gives  `Error: 4 digits only``` is there any other way i can compare the length of characters of the input and check if it equals atleast for 4 digits?

Comment: It looks like you're checking `@filters[:duration][:durations]`, but I can see you're mapping out the same thing a few lines before. Is `@filters[:duration][:durations]` an array or a string?

Comment: Either way you can call  `.length` on it, but you may be checking the wrong item

Comment: it is an array of strings. i would assume .length should work. I tried regex and that gave the error of 4 digits only but it keeps repeating even if the user inputs a number with 4 digits